# DVD/Blu ray burning too fast

Tags: dvd, compact-disc, dvd-burning, blu-ray

Suppose I burn a dvd or blu-ray too fast(faster than the media says it is capable of) but the data verification is a success, Will the dvd be identical to a slower burned one that was also successful(mainly in terms of longevity)?

Obviously burning faster than what is supported increases the likelihood of an error But does it decrease the longevity?

Answer (score 0):

If the data verifies, then you have nothing to worry about. However, as you stated, writing the data faster increases the odds of the verification failing.

Nothing related to the initial burning can increase or decrease the life of the DVD.